# Change ckan production template

Tags: ckan

I change the design in the development, I hardcoded and edit the base.html, page.html and etc. and go to the process in ckan production deployment. But when I access the localhost:8080 it uses the default template. How can I change the production design the same with the design of development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to create a CKAN extension to change the template, that way you can reuse it.

You can check the documentation:
http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/theming/index.html

Here is an example of a custom theme for CKAN

https://github.com/mxabierto/ckanext-dgm